# accessing remote url's in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter, httprequest

I don't know the correct terminology to do a google search.
What I want is to make a POST http request to other url, for example
twitter, from within mi app in google app engine.

If the question is unclear please comment.
Thanks!

Manuel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google provides [urlfetch](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) for this.

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: You can also use the built in urllib or httplib libraries. Urlfetch gives better control, though.